# xmlnode code is not working - access vba

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, geocoding

I am using Access 2010 and am trying to reverse a geocode. I want to specifify a lat\long location then the result to be shown in a listbox. I have a form, with a list box and a command button. The command button has the following onclick event: (I have X out my lat\long address : -) )

```
Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim XMLNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Long
Dim lat As Double, lng As Double


XMLDoc.Load "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=XX.XX,-X.XX&sensor=false"


Do Until XMLDoc.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("No data!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set XMLNode = XMLDoc.selectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")

For i = 0 To XMLNode.childNodes.length - 1

Me.List1.AddItem Item = XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & ": " & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text

Next i
```

However, when I click on the Command Button, the list box is only populated with the word 'False'.  If I paste `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=XX.XX,-X.XX&sensor=false` into a browser, I do get legitimate results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Typo? `.AddItem Item = XMLNode....` this is an equality test then an assignment, remove `Item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code evaluates whether a variable named *Item* is equal to the string *"foo"* and assigns the value of that expression as the new listbox item.

```vb
Me.lstNew.AddItem Item = "foo"
```

If your form's code module included `Option Explicit` in its Declarations section, Access would alert you that the variable *Item* is not defined.  That would be an early clue to where the problem lies.  Always include `Option Explicit` in all your code modules.

To have *Item* recognized as the option name, use `:=` instead of `=`.

```vb
Me.lstNew.AddItem Item:="foo"
```

Comment: You're asking Access to include a colon in the column value with this piece ... `& ": " &`  Why is that a problem?